# Custom content drupal6

Tags: hooks, nodes

I'm new to drupal, so forgive me if my question will be silly :) 
I've a little problem with my first custom content on a drupal 6 installation. My content "biography" is listed in admin/content/types page, but when i click on my type, page reloaded instead of loading /admin/content/node-type/biography

If i force the url in the browser, i'll be redirect to /admin/content/types page again.

Do you know why? I've implemented both the node_info and form hooks, but with no luck.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english! Have a nice day!

**UPDATE**

I cant reply on my own post because i still have low reputation, but...

Bingo..Thank you ARUN! I had been deceived by the fact that it had appeared in content type's list without clearing cache!

have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

That might because of cache. Clear your site cache here **/admin/settings/performance**. Then try to load your content type edit page **/admin/content/node-type/biography**.